# Is preposition "for" used in the sentence correctly?

Tags: prepositions

In the last part of a post, I use this sentence:

We thank all of you for your continued **interest** and **support** **for** our Facebook page.

I know we often say"interest in something" or "support for something." So, is preposition "for" used in the sentence correctly?

Comment: Hello, Daisy. As 'interest' doesn't need a complement, you can get away with this. But it's clumsy. Mind you, 'We thank all of you for your continued interest in and support for our Facebook page.' is a mouthful.

Comment: Do you mean that I can use the preposition "for" in this sentence and that it's correct?

Comment: [A] << We thank all of you for your continued interest and support for our Facebook page. >> means << We thank all of you for your continued interest, and for your  support for our Facebook page. >> and is acceptable though, I'd say,  clumsy.  // << We thank all of you for your continued interest in and support for our Facebook page. >> is acceptable, though it sounds ultra-formal. It correctly pairs up nouns and their usual prepositions, which awkwardly differ here. // << We thank all of you for your continued interest in our Facebook page, and for all your support. >> is what I'd choose.

Answer (score 1):

From the question:

> I know we often say "interest in something" or "support for something."

To combine the two, you don't drop either from the construction:

> ✔ We thank all of you for your continued interest in and support for our Facebook page.

Stylistically, it could also be punctuated differently:

> We thank all of you for your continued interest in, and support for, our Facebook page.
>   We thank all of you for your continued interest in (and support for) our Facebook page.

However, either punctuation would result in *and support for* becoming parenthetical information.

---

If you drop the first preposition, without rephrasing the sentence, then the parallel structure results in a parsing of *interest for*:

> ？ We thank all of you for your continued interest and support for our Facebook page.
>   → We thank all of you for your continued (interest and support) for our Facebook page.
>   → We thank all of you for your continued interest for and support for our Facebook page.

That is at least unidiomatic.

---

While the first version is correct, it also has a formal structure to it that you might want to avoid. If so, you could rephrase the sentence by simply dropping the reference to the Facebook page:

> ✔ We thank all of you for your continued interest and support.

That avoids the use of the different prepositions altogether. Further, if the message is posted on the Facebook page itself, then actually mentioning the page could be redundant.